# Radon-Nikodym derivative and functions

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I have seen in more than one place statements like: 
Let $P$ be a fixed measure and let $Q$ be the measure such that $\frac{dQ}{dP}= \phi$ for some function $\phi$. I just found this in a work: let $Q$ be such that $\frac{dQ}{dP}= \phi^2$ where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function.

My question is then, which regularity conditions do one need to impose in order to have a valid Radon-Nikodym derivative? Smoothness, in what sense?

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)

Comment: I have seen this page, I did try googling it! although, I don't find the result I refer to. I know that a Radon-Nikodym derivative is a function that allows to change measure. My question is: which functions can I assume correspond to a Radon-Nikodym derivative? Can I say that any Lipschitz function is a Radon-Nikodym derivative? Do I need to impose more?

Comment: every integrable (or measurable and non-negative) function $f$ (integrable or measurable respect to a measure, namely $\mu $) defines another measure, namely $\nu $ by $$\nu (A):=\int_A f\mathop{}\!d \mu $$ Then $f=\frac{\mathop{}\!d \nu }{\mathop{}\!d \mu }$ is the corresponding Radon-nikodym derivative. In other words: every integrable (or measurable and non-negative) function is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of it induced measure